# Automatically catching the use of =+ rather than += in Java

Tags: java, operators, compound-operator

I have this horrible habit of typing the below and not catching it until well into testing:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
i =+ j;  //i equals 2, not 3 as intended; assign only, + is unary and works on the j
```

The correct version, of course, would be

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
i += j;  //i equals 3, as intended with additive & assignment compound operator
```

I have made this mistake a zillion times.  It would not surprise me of there is some code out there with a bug in it that escaped a test case.  There has just got to be a way to prevent this systematically.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is a unary + operator in Java? Or is there an implied 0 on the left side? I would have thought your code would produce a compile-time error...

Comment: A pre-commit hook in your VCS that greps for "=+" :-)

Comment: What possible use does a unary + operator have? Absolute(x)?

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: If for no other reason, then for symmetry with the unary minus, I guess. Doesn't pretty much every language have that?

Comment: Mathematically it is just the identity, but it complements the unary -. Some formulas, e.g. a rotation matrix, look nicer with explicit +. Though in light of this question I doubt it is worth it.

Comment: Oh wow... I just opened LINQPad and apparently C# has one too... learn something new every day... (for the record, it has the same effect as recorded above, and no it's not abs(x)).

Comment: I've just grepped the trunk of my main project for =+ =- =* and =/, as a one off search, and all is clear :)

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: the unary + operator at least causes an "Unary Numeric Promotion", that is, eventual unboxing and/or widening conversion. (I don't come to a real use of that...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regularly use tools like [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) and/or [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). Ideally as part of your build process/continuous integration.

You might have to define a custom rule for this, because I don't know if any of those tools recognizes this as a problem by default.

This will not only catch this problem, but also hint at a lot of other potential problems as well.

Comment: Hmmm...using checkstyle but have not looked at the rules in ages and run it in an embarisingly long time. Need to go check that out again.

Comment: +1 for Checkstyle. Used it on a big Java project with Eclipse, with very clever rules (some default, other custom) it was great to catch stupid mistakes and stop worrying about code style/refactoring. Now i miss it dearly on my new, 1 person, C# project under Visual. T_T

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what IDE you use, if it does syntax highlighting, I would modify the highlighting so that it looks for the pattern `=+` and makes it some awful-to-look-at color.

Comment: Ha, hopefully it will help you break the habbit.

Comment: maybe I can wire up a small electric shock ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use standard text utilities, such as

```
find . -name \*.java -exec grep -H "=+" {} \;
```

Comment: Great for a one off check, but I want as part of my development process.  (Just ran it, all is good in my main code base!)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be rigorous in your unit testing. At the moment you're worried about one particular issue, but good unit tests will capture *most* issues (ignoring threading/loading etc.).

You have to decompose your classes/methods such that you can test each chunk of functionality and ensure complete (or as near as you can) coverage.

[Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/) (commercial) or [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) (open source) will manage code coverage for you.

Comment: Unit tests in practise should be relatively straightforwards, however. I tend to be concerned if a unit test has the complexity of the code it's testing, and it's not obvious as to what is being asserted. If that's the case then I'm not convinced the code has been structured/designed with testability in mind. (Note that all the mechanisms mentioned in this thread can have bugs)

Comment: Also, as I work in a small, dynamic start up and not a Bank/NSA/whatever, I  do not (and will not) have 100% code coverage + 100% test coverage.

Comment: I don't think being in a bank/whatever is a prerequisite. My work for non-corporate clients has the same coverage metric as for any other. I really think it's the solution, not just for this problem, but for most issues (whether typos or others)

Comment: I'd also like to catch it on the spot.  Immediate negative reinforcement is what they call it, I think.  Probably going with the most popular answer here...

Answer (score 0):

As balpha commented, an easy way to find this would be to grep for the "=+" in code. It is probably never intentional.